# Why a plug-in would imports and exports one of its own package?

Tags: eclipse, package, eclipse-plugin

In the plug-in `org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.9.100.v20211021-1418`, I find a thing puzzling me that `org.osgi.service.prefs` is one of this plug-in own packages, but in the `MANIFEST.MF`, part of the content is as follows:

```
......
Export-Package: ......,org.osgi.service.prefs;version="1.1.1"
......
Import-Package: ......,org.osgi.service.prefs;version="[1.1.1,1.2)"
```

Why does it both import and export a package of its own ?

Comment: I guess so that the bundles with `Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences` get the package `org.osgi.service.prefs`, although it is not included in the bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.preferences`.

Comment: The current 3.10.0.v20220503-1634 doesn't do this. It has Require-Bundle org.osgi.service.prefs;bundle-version="[1.1.0,1.2.0)";visibility:=reexport instead, which suggests it was about re-exporting

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, with your explanation I understand the purpose of this. But in the old version `3.9.100.v20211021-1418`, the plugin has a package `org.osgi.service.prefs` of its own, imports another package `org.osgi.service.prefs`, and then exports a package `org.osgi.service.prefs`, so will it not cause conflicts? Which package do other plugins that depend on this package use?

Comment: With this trick bundles with `Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences;bundle-version="[3.9.0,4.0.0)"` using the `org.osgi.service.prefs` package will work with the old and the new versions. Without this trick (`Export-Package: org.osgi.service.prefs;version="1.1.1"`), the new version would break those bundles. For bundles with `Import-Package: org.osgi.service.prefs` the trick is not needed and does not matter.